# How filter array of objects elements mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following schema:

```
User: {
  age: Number,
  name: String,
  comments: {
    added: Date,
    body: String
  }
}
```

I need get all users, with comments added greater than a custom date.

**Example data:**

```
[{
  "name": "John",
  "age: 21,
  "comments": [{
     "added": 21-01-12,
     "body": "blabla1"    
  }, {
     "added": 21-02-12,
     "body": "blabla2"    
  }, {
     "added": 21-01-10,
     "body": "blabla3"   
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Bruno",
  "age: 33,
  "comments": [{
     "added": 21-01-10,
     "body": "ololo1"    
  }, {
     "added": 21-02-12,
     "body": "ololo2"    
  }, {
     "added": 21-01-09,
     "body": "ololo3"   
  }]
}]
```

I need all users with all comments greater than `01-01-11` without comments less than this date.

**Expected result:**

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age: 21,
  "comments": [{
     "added": 21-01-12,
     "body": "blabla1"    
  }, {
     "added": 21-02-12,
     "body": "blabla2"    
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Bruno",
  "age: 33,
  "comments": [{
     "added": 21-02-12,
     "body": "ololo2"    
  }]
}
```

How can I go about this ?

Comment: take a look at [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)

Comment: it's correct filter, but in result i have all users, with empty comments, and etc, but i want only users with needed comments

Comment: Please add the query you have so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const findQuery = [
    {$unwind: "$comments" },
    {$match: {"comments.added": {$gt: lastUpdate} } },
    {$group: {_id: "$_id", comments: {$push: "$comments"} } }
];

User.aggregate(findQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter a date field in Mongoose (and mongo), you need to use $gte, $gt, $lt, $lte. In your specific example, you need $gte (greater than or equal)

So, if your model is User
User.find({comments.added : {$gte : new Date(2011, 1, 1)}}, function(err, comments) {

});

Except if there are some reasons, I may propose you to prefer ISODate that are more accurate, and you do the same to filter entries

mph

Comment: I use isodate, it's for quick example.
other comment's (with date $lt: new Date(2011, 1, 1)) will not be in result?

Comment: Just did against my MongoDB database using ISODate: User.find({comments.add: {$gte: new ISODate("2011-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")}}, function(err, entries) {

Comment: I do this, but in result i have users with all comments, but i want to get comments only $gt date. But in result i have all comments(

Comment: Oh! I understand the misunderstanding, bear in mind your comments are embedded documents as proposed you got the documents that match the filter $gte new ISODate, the documents, period. Except if I am wrong, you cannot expect from Mongoose to remove some embedded documents because they don't match the filter, if there is at least one document that matches the filter. You should prune after your embedded documents with plain JS

Comment: filter in js - very hard way. I believe that one should always try to make database tools. I found a solution now)